# How to move some file to a subdirectory?

Tags: mv

I have -

```
|Books  
  |--LaTeX
  |--LaTeX_wikibook.pdf  
  |--LaTex_advanced.pdf
  |--vim_wikibook.pdf
  |--vimLaTeX.pdf
```

I want -

```
|Books  
  |--LaTeX
  |   |--LaTeX_wikibook.pdf  
  |   |--LaTex_advanced.pdf
  |   |--vimLaTeX.pdf
  |--vim_wikibook.pdf
```

I want to move only those file having substring `LaTeX` to the folder `LaTeX`. How can I do this in one command?

Comment: Did you try something like `mv *LaTeX*.* LaTeX/`? Sorry, on my phone, so can't test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this ...

```
cd Books/
mv *LaTeX*.pdf LateX/
```

You can exchange the "pdf" for a "*" to if you have other extensions.

Comment: I think you missed the capitalization in `LaTeX/` :)

Comment: Hmmm? Where? >:-D

Comment: You wrote `mv *LaTeX*.pdf LateX/`, it should be `mv *LaTeX*.pdf LaTeX/`. Hehe